# Deserializing returns null object Java

Tags: java, file, serialization

Currently writing an application like [Booking](https://www.booking.com/index.el.html) and I am in the stage where i want to store my infomation in files. I have created a `Serializable` `Database` class which has a field with a pathname and 2 methods for read/write . I have about 8 other classes which extend the Database and each holds a `Hashmap` and some querying methods. Naturally I read the `Databases` from my files before i start the application and i write before exiting, but I ran into a problem where the objects I am reading are all **null**. I've been at it for 2 hours now and I need a second opinion. This is the database's read/write methods:

```
public void write() {
        try {
            File temp = new File(this.filename);
            temp.createNewFile(); // create file if not present
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(this.filename);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            objectOut.writeObject(this);
            objectOut.close();
            System.out.println("The Object  was successfully written to a file");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Object read() {
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            File temp = new File(this.filename);
            temp.createNewFile(); // create file if not present
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(this.filename);
            ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            obj = objectIn.readObject();
            System.out.println("The Object was successfully read from the file");
            objectIn.close();
        } catch (EOFException ex) {
            return obj;
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And here is the way I load them (Which is probably the problem) in my `Application` class

```
private void loadData() {
        accommodationReviewsDatabase = (AccommodationReviews) accommodationReviewsDatabase.read();
        brokerAccommodationsDatabase = (BrokerAccommodations) brokerAccommodationsDatabase.read();
        credentialsUserDatabase = (CredentialsUser) credentialsUserDatabase.read();
        customerReviewsDatabase = (CustomerReviews) customerReviewsDatabase.read();
        userConfirmationsDatabase = (UserConfirmations) userConfirmationsDatabase.read();
        userMessagesDatabase = (UserMessages) userMessagesDatabase.read();
    }

    private void writeData() {
        accommodationReviewsDatabase.write();
        brokerAccommodationsDatabase.write();
        credentialsUserDatabase.write();
        customerReviewsDatabase.write();
        userConfirmationsDatabase.write();
        userMessagesDatabase.write();
    }
```

Some extra information that may be asked :

- All my classes that I am storing are serializable
- The files I am storing the databases are all *.ser (Thats the extension I found)
- The files are stored inside the project

Comment: If your `read()` method completes without an EOFException, it ends with `return null;`. Why not `return obj;`?

Comment: @khelwood My thinking was that EOF will be reached anyway so I'll return the object in the try-catch. Am I wrong?

Comment: If your code successfully reads the object, that code should not throw an exception. Also, if it does throw an exception, you probably want some indication, not just silently returning. Silent catch blocks deny you information that would help debugging.

Comment: @khelwood wow this fixed it. It works as intended now,but I am still confused. Doesn't EOF reach every single time I read so I can just return the `obj` ? I was returning null at the last line because I thought the code would never reach that

Comment: No, the EOF exception means that it ran out of input while it was trying to read your object. If it successfully reads your object, it won't throw the exception (unless you try to read more).

Comment: That clears it,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `read()` method completes without an EOFException, it ends with `return null;`. You should `return obj;`, the object you read.

You should not expect that EOFException will be thrown if your read succeeds. The EOFException would indicate that it ran out of data while it was trying to read your object, and could not complete successfully.

If you *do* get an EOFException, it is probably a good idea to give some indication instead of silently returning. Silent catch blocks deny you information that could be useful for debugging.